# Graphical artifacts with RTX 3090 GPU under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

I have a computer running Ubuntu 20.04 with a GeForce RTX 3090 graphics card. The system works fine for the most part, and I have been running PyTorch on the GPU without problems. However, the display output itself has annoying visual artifacts. [Here is what I am seeing, the green parts flicker rapidly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJnHR.jpg) Specifically, it seems to affect pixels that are completely black or perhaps just have one of the RGB components set to 0.

I encountered the same problem under Ubuntu 18.04. The monitor works fine when plugged into a different computer.

Here is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
vaclav@computer ~> nvidia-smi
Thu Jul 22 12:35:37 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:2D:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 66%   61C    P2   254W / 390W |  14846MiB / 24259MiB |     48%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

The drivers are quite recent, could there be another cause of the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on personal experience the most likely cause of the problem is defective card. Contact Nvidia and do RMA.

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing. I'll see if it annoys me enough to go through the whole RMA hassle.